# Getting the value from a prompt box

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Hello
I'm trying to make a simple web chat, and I want the user to choose his name when he first load the chat page and for this I'm using this function:

```
function Login(un)
{
var x=prompt("Please enter your name","");
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// Използваните браузъри
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// Кой ли ползва тези версии..
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","login.php?u="+un,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I put this in the head section and then in the body onload... I call the function but can't figure out how to extract the text from the prompt box.I tried

```
login(getElementsByName('x').value)
```

But obvously that's not the way, so, please help.
Thanks
Leron

Comment: Does `x` from `var x=prompt("Please enter your name","");` not contain the value? I don't see where you are using it after you call the prompt.

Comment: Well I tried this - changed the name to function Login() and then xmlhttp.open("GET","login.php?u="+x,true); - add the variable 'x' in login.php?u=+x, but still nothing

Comment: Right after `var x=prompt("Please enter your name","");` put `alert(x);` ... does it contain the value?

Comment: Yes, in fact I just misunderstood the problem.The 'x' has the value and the actual problem was in my MySQL query.Sorry for misleading, you but really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x=prompt("Please enter your name","");
```

Then x has the value entered in the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

```
var login = getElementsByName('loginboxname').value;
```

Just make sure you replace "loginboxname" with the actual name of your login box. The variable "login" should then the value of that box.